# White space caused by outline

Tags: html, css

After I added 12px outline to the div which contain a background image, on the left and right hand side it appear some white space

*Image:*
[image]

How do I remove the white space?

Comment: Have you tried using `img {min-width: 100%;}` ? Not sure what's the intended.

Comment: Please post some code so we can help you out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that image you use .png but this image does not have a transparent background, you should use transparent background or fix with images for min-width: 100%;[image]